# How to get camel with transactions "without J2EE"

Tags: transactions, apache-camel

I am using standalone Camel framework and i want to have transaction routes. I checked that simply using .transacted() does not works since i do not have PlatformTransactionManager in the context.

Can you point me a way to properly configure this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Camel (.. or actually Spring which is used by Camel to handle transactions) what transaction manager you want to use.

A transaction manager can be a single resource transaction manager based on the resource you integrate with (Database or JMS system) or it can be a distributed transaction manager able to synchronize transactions between multiple resources, such as JavaEE server transaction managers or stand alone ones such as Atomikos, bitronix, JBossTM etc.

If you want single resource transaction (non XA), there are very good configuration examples at this [page](http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html) for both JMS (ActiveMQ) and JDBC (Derby). It should be straight forward to switch to other JMS/Database products.

Setting up a standalone XA transaction manager is not too hard, but the configuration will differ alot depending on involved components. There are some examples in the Camel in Action book and a lot of [blogs](http://blog.bigrocksoftware.com/2010/04/30/atomikos-activemq-hibernate/)/stack overflow posts and [articles](http://fusesource.com/docs/esbent/7.0/camel_tx/XaJms-Overview.html) [on the web](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks. I've read Camel in action ... examples there are very nice when you have all pieces up and running but i did not find them useful on how to configure ... let's say, as you said, how to tell camel (spring) what transaction manager i wanted to use. Maybe i am asking this because my lack of knowledge on Spring and i should better look at Spring and some of the stand alone XA servers you have pointed.

Comment: Yes, from a camel perspective - all you need is a spring PlatformTransactionManager. You need to look for details elsewhere, especially if you use some XA manager. Even then, you might need special config for various jms/database systems.